# How can make a "Fade Out to silence then Fade in" script in Sound Forge 11?

Tags: automation, silence, script

I have a religious recitation that has long pauses. There are people cheering at the end of a verse, or coughing and just general background noise during the silences, with I would like to remove.

I'd like to do this by fading out the end of a verse (about half a second), silence the audio inbetween (all different lengths) and then fade in at the begining of the next verse (about half a second).

I tried to use a noise gate but over a 40 minute recitation its difficult to make sure its working and to get the right balance - it would take too long and it would be easier and quicker to do this manually. However if the fade out, silence and fade in were all once action it would make things a lot faster.

I would like help with a macro/script that would do this?

Answer (score 1):

A script would have to be able to distinguish between dialogue you want to keep, and "noise", as thresholds and other means wouldn't work in this scenario. It would be easier (IMO) to simply place markers (M-key) where you wish to silence the track, prior to/post your fade-in/out points.

Then select the space between the markers, click 'Process' and reduce the volume to zero. Return to your markers, and apply your fade/in-outs. Then adjust/reduce the space (silence) to taste. [2c]

Comment: it will depend on the selection. I don't want to do it over the whole audio in one action, rather select the part of the audio I want to edit and process that as ONE action rather than three. Incidently, I am using the Graphic fade which seems to be doing what I want to.

Comment: The problem with a script (again) would be in determining amplitude 'thresholds' accurately, and applying what you want to do to the right things. The 'three step process', is this: Make a selection you wish to silence. Go to "process", select: **[Sys] Mute**, hit OK. Select _another_  section, hit: **F4** (mutes that selection)... _repeat_ for the entire track.

Select a portion you want to fade-in, go to "process", click the **fade-in** (ramp) icon. Select the next fade-in part, hit **F4**. Do the same for all your fade-out points. Save changes. Done.